# How can I protect the account of the first user, and not allow administration users to alter it?

Tags: 7, users

I want to not allow users with the permission to administer users to alter the account for the first registered user (the one created during the installation of Drupal).
I also want to not allow them to view the user profile for that user.

Is there a module that allows this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [User Protect](http://drupal.org/project/userprotect) module should suite your use case.

> This module allows fine-grained access control of user administrators, by providing various editing protection for users. The protections can be specific to a user, or applied to all users in a role.
>
> *Note: User Protect has a complicated configuration — please take the time to read the very extensive module help before using it!*
>
> The following protections are supported:
>
> - username
> - e-mail address
> - password
> - status changes
> - roles
> - deletion
> - OpenID identities
> - all edits (any accessed via user/X/edit)
>
> When a protection is enabled for a specified user (or the protection is enabled because the user belongs to a role that has the protection), it prevents the editing operation in question that anyone might try to perform on the user—unless an administrator who is permitted to bypass the protection is editing the specified user. The module will protectfields by disabling them at user/X/edit.
>
> User administrators may be configured to bypass specified protections, on either a global or per-administrator basis.
>
> These protections are valid both when trying to edit the user directly from their user/X/edit page, or using the mass user editing
> operations.
>
> The module also provides protection at the paths user/X/edit and user/X/delete, should anyone try to visit those paths directly.
>
> *Note: this module is compatible with the [RoleAssign](http://drupal.org/project/roleassign) module.*